# Render component with async ComponentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

I would like to create a `<textarea>` that behaves like `console.log`.

```
class Console extends Component {
...
    async componentDidMount() {
        for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
           setTimeout(() => {this.setState({message: 'updateMessage' + millis()}, 1000);
        }
    }
    render() {
       return <textarea>{this.state.messsage}</textarea>
    }
}
```

I expected this code to update the UI in realtime. The issue is that `componentDidMount` waits until all the `setTimeout`'s functions are executed in the loop then renders everything all at once.

Is there something I am misunderstanding? Thanks

Comment: that's working as intended since you  all the set time out resolve at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Your setTimeout are all resolved at the same time, and your messages are not in array, hence it's overwritten each time.

If I use a delay promise, instead of set timeout, then the state will be updated accordingly.

```
const delay = async () => {
  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000)
})
}
```

Example: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-gauss-4prg5?file=/src/index.js)

```
class Console extends Component {
...
    async componentDidMount() {
        for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
           this.setState({message: 'updateMessage' + millis()})
           await delay()
        }
    }
    render() {
       return <textarea>{this.state.messsage}</textarea>
    }
}
```